# Extract video content from post to display on front page

Tags: wp-query, media-settings

Well I know how to extract image from post.But what about videos?I want to show first video from post .

```
<?php $args = array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => 'post-format-video'
    )
  )
);
query_posts( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  the_title();
  the_post_video();
      the_post_video_first();
 // echo get_post_format();
  echo '<br />';
endwhile; else:
  echo 'no';
endif;
wp_reset_query();      
?>`enter code here`
```

Thus the_post_video() will return first video and the_post_video() return/grab every video inside the post.

CHEERS

Comment: I tried with this but it returns the video file name.How can I show it with video player?

Comment: This highly depends how precisely you define "video". Elaborate with some examples?